# using c++ static library(.lib ) in c# project?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, .lib

I am trying to make c# project and i need to use a solver which i found on the internet to do some calculation but this solver is a static library which writing in c++ .

it is so difficult to rewrite this library in .Net and that will take too much time.

i read some articles about it liking making a managed c++ but i don't know what is the simplest solution to use that .lib in c# project ?

[this is the static library](http://clb.demon.fi/projects/rectangle-bin-packing)

Comment: Refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/299da822-5539-4e5b-9ba7-b614e564c9f4/presenting-a-c-library-lib-for-use-in-c-project?forum=vcgeneral) link. The link shows the way to handle your issue.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=lib+to+dll+converter

Comment: Managed C++ is almost the only way. You just have expose the managed interface to the static library. That said, C++ is completely crazy - even just compiling a simple project like this with a statically linked library might take you much longer than you expect. If your only significant experience is with C#, this might prove quite a challenge :)

Comment: @Luaan
i made it but i have a problem !!
i have class GuillotineBinPack which is not managed c++ , it is working well in my application but the problem is i want to create some function that i had to pass to it an instance from that class by reference so do i have to change that class to managed c++ or there is other way better than modifying that class ?

Comment: Why would you ever need to pass a class? You really only want to pass structures and primitives, not classes (How would that even work? As a proxy to calls to managed code?). What are you trying to do?

Comment: thank you :D , i fixed it in other way i made that function return two parameters using std::pair instead of using references  ...

Comment: @Luaan
can you please check this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620421/managed-class-member-varible-from-managed-struct