# Managed class member varible from managed struct

Tags: managed-c++

I need help in making a member variable for a **managed** class of managed struct...

I tried to fix this, but the error didn't disappear till I made that class non-managed by removing "ref".

You may see this picture to see the class and the struct
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=149mgie&s=8

```
public ref struct RectResult
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

public ref  class GullotinePackedBin
{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    vector<RectResult> packedRectangles;
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with managed C++, but isn't `vector` unmanaged? I expect that if you remove it (or replace it with `List`), it will compile.

Comment: thank you very much , i double checked what if vector is unmanaged or managed and i found that it is managed but i had to include Header: <cliext/vector>
and use namespace: cliext
:D

Comment: is there List in managed c++ ?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be - it's a normal .NET class, so it should be available for managed C++.

Comment: @Luaan
this is my function in managed c++ http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xe36kn&s=8
this is how i call it http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=okosbr&s=8
 is it possible to return object from managed c++ to c# ?
i even tried to create object and send it as ref but it didn't accept it .

Comment: Oh, so you come from unmanaged C++ background? What exactly does happen when you try to call the method from C#?

Comment: yes i came from unmanaged C++ background :)
and thanks god i fixed it but i have other problem in trying to add some features in the code !
i tried to use Enum but it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756943/enum-in-managed-managed-c

Comment: The image link is (effectively) broken.